# Grab part of filename with Python

Tags: python, filenames

Newbie here.

I've just been working with Python/coding for a few days, but I want to create a script that grabs parts of filenames corresponding to a certain pattern, and outputs it to a textfile.

So in my case, let's say I have four .pdf like this:

```
aaa_ID_8423.pdf
bbbb_ID_8852.pdf
ccccc_ID_7413.pdf
dddddd_ID_4421.pdf

(Note that they are of variable length.)
```

I want the script to go through these filenames, grab the string after "ID_" and before the filename extension.

Can you point me in the direction to which Python modules and possibly guides that could assist me?

Comment: If those are the only numbers in the string you can use this, oh and the library is re
ID = re.findall(r"[0-9]+", *stringname")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using the re module as mentioned in other answers.

```
# Libraries
import re

# Example filenames. Use glob as described below to grab your pdf filenames
file_list = ['name_ID_123.pdf','name2_ID_456.pdf'] # glob.glob("*.pdf") 

for fname in file_list:
    res = re.findall("ID_(\d+).pdf", fname)
    if not res: continue
    print res[0] # You can append the result to a list
```

And below should be your output. You should be able to adapt this to other patterns.

```
# Output
123
456
```

Goodluck!

Answer (score 6):

Here's another alternative, using `re.split()`, which is probably closer to the spirit of exactly what you're trying to do (although solutions with `re.match()` and `re.search()`, among others, are just as valid, useful, and instructive):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split("[_.]", "dddddd_ID_4421.pdf")[-2]
'4421'
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

If the numbers are variable length, you'll want the regex module "re"

```
import re

# create and compile a regex pattern
pattern = re.compile(r"_([0-9]+)\.[^\.]+$")

pattern.search("abc_ID_8423.pdf").group(1)
Out[23]: '8423'
```

Regex is generally used to match variable strings.  The regex I just wrote says:

Find an underscore ("_"), followed by a variable number of digits ("[0-9]+"), followed by the last period in the string ("\.[^\.]+$")

Comment: To elaborate on this, please take a look at the Regular Expressions library found in https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html 

There's also a couple of regular expression cheat sheets floating around the web including https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/python which explain how KCzar's program work

Answer (score 2):

You can use the os module in python and do a listdir to get a list of filenames present in that path like so:

```
import os
filenames = os.listdir(path)
```

Now you can iterate over the filenames list and look for the pattern which you need using regular expressions:

```
import re
for filename in filenames:
    m = re.search('(?<=ID_)\w+', filename)
    print (m)
```

The above snippet will return the part of the filename following ID_ and prints it out. So, for your example, it would return 4421.pdf, 8423.pdf etc. You can write a similar regex to remove the .pdf part.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have tried this with an actual file and get this response:

 `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10d10aac0>`

It seems like it's finding the ID_ at a location, but can't get it to output the string. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why put the import inside the for loop?

Comment: Because I wasn't paying attention when I wrote the answer ;). Thanks for the correction. Editing it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use glob, which is a python module for file globbing. From the python help page the usage is as follows:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('./[0-9].*')
['./1.gif', './2.txt']
>>> glob.glob('*.gif')
['1.gif', 'card.gif']
>>> glob.glob('?.gif')
['1.gif']
```